# css merge box shadows

Tags: html, css

I want to make an horizontal navigation bar with an unordered list and list items which represent the elements of the bar :

I used a width of 25% for each element so that they would fit exactly in the bar and a box-shadow to create a border around each list item because if i decided to use a border, the elements would not fit inside the bar :

```css
#bar {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  background: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
}
.foo {
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1pt black;
}
```

```html
<ul id="bar">
  <li class="foo">Foo 1</li>
  <li class="foo">Foo 2</li>
  <li class="foo">Foo 3</li>
  <li class="foo">Foo 4</li>
</ul>
```

However, because there are two shadows between each element, I get a shadow two times thicker between them.

[image: navigation bar]

Is there a way to somehow merge those shadows ?

I tried border-collapse: collapse but it didn't change a thing.
I would also like to avoid using an outline because I want to style this menu further.

Comment: If you only need to target modern browsers, you could look into `calc()`. That would allow you to set the width of each item to `25% - 1pt` for a border. Then you could use a negative margin to collapse the inner borders.

Answer (score 4):

How about this? 
 Just use `box-sizing: border-box;` and the borders won't affect your width.

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/amrn/4ekr1g96/)

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#bar
{
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  background: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
}

.foo
{
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  list-style: none;
  /* box-shadow: 0 0 0 1pt black; */
  border-top: 1px black solid;
  border-left:1px black solid;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}

.foo:last-child {
  border-right: 1px black solid;
}
```

Comment: but this solution does not use `box-shadow`, does it?

Comment: He didn't say that it has to be `box-shadow`, he said "if i decided to use a border, the elements would not fit inside the bar". So I gave him a way to use borders without the problem he mentioned.

Comment: Yes, after comparing the question and your answer more closely it is clear to me. The solution you propose is more elegant and *semantic*, as the questioner *means* "elements with border", not "elements with shadow". +1!

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably the answer from Amr Noman
But, if you really want to fix your shadows, you can style the bar with same shadow that you are using (for the borders)

And style the second .foo and followings to the left, so that they fill the inner borders.

I have set the external *borders* blue so it's easy to see what is what

```css
#bar {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  background: lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1pt blue;
  
}
.foo {
  line-height: 30px;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  list-style: none;
}

.foo:nth-child(n+2) {
  box-shadow: -1pt 0 0 0  black;
  
}
```

```html
<ul id="bar">
  <li class="foo">Foo 1</li>
  <li class="foo">Foo 2</li>
  <li class="foo">Foo 3</li>
  <li class="foo">Foo 4</li>
</ul>
```